# How to get match of a pattern even if it is splitted by characters using a bash command (similar to grep)?

Tags: bash, scripting, grep, command

I'm trying to output all the lines of a file which contain a specific word/pattern even if it contains other characters between its letters.

Let's say we have a bunch of domain names and we want to filter out all those that contain "***paypal***" inside, I would like to have this kind of output :

```
pay-pal-secure.com
payppal.net
etc...
```

I was wondering if this is possible with grep or does it exist something else that might do it.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `paypal` with regexp `p.*a.*y.*p.*a.*l` to allow all characters between the letters.

**Update**:

Use extended regular expression `p.{0,2}a.{0,2}y.{0,2}p.{0,2}a.{0,2}l` to limit characters between the letters to none to two.

Example: `grep -E 'p.{0,2}a.{0,2}y.{0,2}p.{0,2}a.{0,2}l' file`

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: That's a good idea but it would give unwanted results, is there a way to do that but limited to one or two interruption between each letter ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use [`agrep`](https://www.tgries.de/agrep/) (approximate grep):

```
$ agrep -By paypal file
agrep: 2 words match within 1 error
pay-pal-secure.com
payppal.net
```

Comment: Mmmh seems it doesn't work for me, it only outputs full word match

Comment: `agrep -V`: _This is agrep version 3.0, 1994._

Comment: You mean this is deprecated in the newest versions ? Mine is 3.41.5.

Comment: I have no idea. I downloaded 3.41 which claims to be 3.40 but it works. I'm going to stick to 3.0, though.